# Unable to load class fields into child classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

1ST STEP

```
public class Catalog
{
    public int CatalogId { get; set; }
    public string CatalogName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

2ND STEP IN MODEL

```
public class Catalogs : Catalog { }

public class GetCatalogResponse
{
    public Catalogs Catalogs { get; set; }
}
```

3RD STEP

```
var resp = new Models.GetCatalogResponse();
```

In this scenario, I'm unable to load catalog fields into var resp

Comment: You need to initialize the and assign some values to those parameter to be access. I am not really getting, what do you want to do with it. you can take a look for https://dotnetfiddle.net/UJRnLP

Answer (score 1):

If what you are after is to extend the Catalog class to include custom fields, then try the following:

```
public class Catalog
{
    public int CatalogId { get; set; }
    public string CatalogName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class CatalogExtension : Catalog
{
    public string YourCustomValue { get; set; }

    public CatalogExtension(Catalog catalog)
    {
        CatalogId = catalog.CatalogId;
        CatalogName = catalog.CatalogName;
        StartDate = catalog.StartDate;
        EndDate = catalog.EndDate;
        IsDeleted = catalog.IsDeleted;
        YourCustomValue = "test"
    }

    public CatalogExtension()
    {
        // Assign values however you want
    }
}
```

Then, you can get a new CatalogExtension object by:

```
var resp = new CatalogExtension(catalog);
```

or

```
var resp = new CatalogExtension();
```